# Finding the center of drawn rings in an image

Tags: python-3.x

I have a black and white .PNG image of rings and his ascii image. I need to find the center itself and its coordinates to further find the radii of the circles. How can I implement this in python?
There are several circles in the image, but they all have the same center.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can link the image. You can use openCV for this. If you can link the image, I can give a solution.

Comment: Hello, here you can see the images at this link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eZMOGt8pAnWB1LoS2zIkW1rU3qsHc16A?usp=sharing

Comment: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/07/21/detecting-circles-images-using-opencv-hough-circles/ you can check this